# What does l=1 do in a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql that has `l=1` in select.  I am confused if this an assignment operator or equality check?

```
select col_1, col_2...
  CASE
    WHEN col_1 IS NOT NULL AND l=1 THEN 'COL_1'
    ...               
  END employee_id_type,
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: It's an equality check. `l`is presumably some column in the query.

Comment: Equality check. Post the rest of the code before END and your table structure if you need more information.

Comment: It's possible it actually read `1=1` (number 1 being equal to the number 1), this is often used as a placeholder to identify a free spot in the where clause by a few database pre-processors that have their own filters to apply to the query.

Comment: show us the table DDL, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language

Comment: @scragar: Indeed. Often used for formatting in our company.

Comment: The equality operator in SQL is `=`, so `l=1` checks if the value column `l` is equal to the value `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be confused, Ada is the ancestor of the PL/SQL language, that's why we use the equal `=` sign to compare values. To assign a value to a variable we use the `:=` sign

The double equals `==` sign is comparison sign from C/C++ and other languages.

Also if you check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators) you will find out that `=` is the `equal to` operator

Comment: This has nothing to do with PL/SQL, it's standard SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHofman I updated my answer according to your comment

Comment: Now it's getting even more off-topic on PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Probably in this case `l` is a field in a table. This condition checks if `l` equals `1`.